# How to use Eclipse CDT/C++ for profiling

Tags: c++, eclipse, profiler, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to use perf tool in eclipse CDT(latest) for my application on Ubuntu 14.04.

I'm getting an error when I Right click on project->Profiling Tools-> Profile with Perf.
`Error within Debug UI: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`
None of the profiling tools are working.

Am I missing any specific configuration? Also If i try to simply profile as application it gives error like
`invalid version "": invalid format`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse and CDT are you using, I can't find the "perf" menu entry in my CDT 8.5 ? It seems to me that perf integration comes from linux tools project (https://eclipse.org/linuxtools/projectPages/perf/). Have you installed it ?

Answer (score 2):

Type `perf` in a terminal and see the error prompt. It should advice you to install a specific version of linux-tools, for instance `linux-tools-3.2-75` where “3.2-75” is the version number of your kernel. It solved the problem for me.

Moreover, on Ubuntu 14.04, `linux-tools-generic-lts-trusty` should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You could compile with the [`-pg` compiler flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) then use [gprof(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gprof.1.html) for profiling. BTW, you don't need Eclispe to compile a C++ program (I would suggest using [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)).

Of course you can run [perf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf.1.html) in a terminal.

<sup>It looks like Eclipse is mostly an annoyance to you. Then why do you use it? A lot of C++ software is developed *without* Eclipse. Most of the C++ free software developers I met don't use Eclipse, and I never used it for C++ code; I am very happy with Emacs.</sup>

Comment: One reason many people decide to use Eclipse CDT for C++ development is that many IDE features (code completion, code analysis, jump to definition/declaration, jump from error to code, visual debugger, git integration, cmake integration, project explorer, go-to-any file, etc.) works out of the box, while to achieve the same functionality in Emacs requires a lot of manual configuration and installation of third-party packages.

Comment: Link to "compiler flag" is broken.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. 
It was perf was not installed in my system. I m using Linux operating system. Once it was installed I was able to resolve this issue.
Thanks everyone for their valuable time.